# Where can I inspect Vue.js generated render functions?

Tags: vue.js, debugging, browser

An exception breakpoint once led me to a render function generated by the Vue template compiler for one of my Vue components.

This striked me as a "*Hey, I now understand how this template system works!*", but I didn't pay attention to where that was in the webpack tree.

Now I'd like to inspect the code for other components and may be set a breakpoint here and there, but when I browse the active javascript sources in the browser debugger pane, I can't find any of this generated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the compiled render functions can be found in the sources tree under the `.` folder of `webpack://`. It can be a bit tricky to find the right one though because there are multiple files for each `.vue` file. The other files will contain other bits of the component. The file containing the `render` function should be pretty obvious when you find it, it should start `var render = function() {`. For example, in one of my test applications I can see the `render` function for `app.vue` at `webpack:///./src/app.vue?91e4`, though that last part will vary.

If you want to insert a breakpoint for your own component then you can sneak it in via a method. This can also be a quick way to find the right file.

Within the template, make a call to a method, I've called it `breakpoint`:

```html
{{ breakpoint() }}
```

Then in the method:

```js
breakpoint () {
  debugger
  return ''
}
```

You can then walk one level up the stack to see the compiled `render` function.

Of course you don't necessarily have to use a `debugger` statement for this. You could just set a browser breakpoint in a suitable method (or introduce one if one doesn't already exist). So long as the method is called within the template it should give you access to the compiled `render` function.

To set a breakpoint that way you should just need to navigate to the relevant `.vue` file in the `webpack://` section of the sources tree. That file is usually easy to find directly under the `webpack://` heading.

**Update:**

Once you've found the file containing the `render` function using a breakpoint you can then find the file in the sources tree using *'Reveal in sidebar'*:

[image: Screenshot of context menu]

Comment: Your breakpoint method works. It points me to `webpack:///src/components/MyComp.vue?b080`. But this file doesn't appear in the webpack tree (which has other file for the same component).

Comment: @Rtbo Initially I thought the files weren't in the Webpack tree but I was looking in the wrong place. In Chrome, once you've found the correct file using a breakpoint, right click on the tab at the top that shows the file name and then select *'Reveal in sidebar'*. If that doesn't work then I guess it really isn't in your sources tree.

Comment: The problem I have is from using Firefox. In Chrome I can see all the files in the webpack tree, without setting any breakpoint. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Rtbo Agreed, I can't see them in the tree in Firefox. Clicking *'Reveal in Tree'* doesn't seem to be able to find them either.